# Cohomology of Lie group $E_8$, e.g. $H^d(E_8,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, topological-groups, spectral-sequences

What is the $d$-th cohomology of a Lie group $E_8$, say $H^d(E_8,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ coefficient?

I suppose that there are many nontrivial groups of $H^d(E_8,\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, for many of $d$.

But I could not show them myself. I find a useful Ref [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Fung.pdf).

Any systematic results will be highly appreciated.

We may view this from (i) the topological cohomology of the Lie group manifold $E_8$, or from (ii) the group cohomology of $E_8$. Either results/answers are very welcome!

Comment: You mean the compact form of $E_8$? Or some other real form, or the complex form?

Comment: Concerning (ii): By a well-known lemma, the group cohomology of a compact Lie group $G$ (with any coefficients) is trivial in higher degrees. This is because the group cohomology is a derived functor of the functor of $G$-invariants, and $G$ being compact implies that the latter is exact.